# How to condense multiple matrix row results into one for each factor and write it to tsv file?

Tags: r, formatting

My output is in the following format:

type name factor1 factor2 
 
 1     a  34       4       5 
 
 2    a   34       3       7 
 
 3    a   22       1       3 
 
 4    a   21       3       4 
 
 5    a   21       3       5

Here is code to get the output:

```
data<-as.data.frame(rbind(c("a",34,4,5), c("a", 34, 3, 7), c("a", 22, 1, 3), c("a", 21,3,4), c("a", 21,3,5)))
names(data)<-c("type", "name", "factor1", "factor2")
```

I am looking to transform the above to an output to one where each "name" column has only one row. This new format has to be written in a tsv file that will be used in another function (by Python).

type    name   factor1   factor2 
 
1    a   34       4,3       5,7 
 
3    a   22       1         3 
 
4    a   21       3         4,5

Sorry, I don't know how to get spaces to show clearly per row. For example, row 1 has "4,3" under "factor1" column and "5,7" under factor2 column. Hope this helps.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    group_by(type, name) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(toString(sort(unique(.)))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked great! Exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `summarise_all` to apply multiple functions on the variable, we can also define a customized function and pass it to `summarise`. Note this is useful when you want do complicated manipulation on variables.

```
library(dplyr)
func <- function(value){
  return(paste(unique(value), collapse = ','))
}

data %>% 
  group_by(type, name) %>%
  summarise(factor1 = func(factor1), factor2 = func(factor2))

# or use summarise_each in new dplyr verion
data %>% 
  group_by(type, name) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(func))
```

This is the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   type [?]
    type   name factor1 factor2
  <fctr> <fctr>   <chr>   <chr>
1      a     21       3     4,5
2      a     22       1       3
3      a     34     4,3     5,7
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you! In the mean time I started using dplyr library, but didn't think of this. :) Thanks.